# How do I do post-compile bundling in Maven?

Tags: maven, kotlin

I have a maven project that contains some Kotlin source files and some web resources (HTML/CSS).  During the compile phase, the Kotlin source is compiled to JavaScript and ends up in the build output location, along with some other folders that I am not familiar with.

I would like a build step that occurs after the compile is finished that will copy my resources and compiled output and dependencies (kotlin.js) into a folder with the correct hierarchy that I deploy or debug.

I know how to copy the resources into the build output folder, but the build output folder appears to have some other files in it that are auto-generated by maven which I do not want to deploy.

Ideally, I would also like the clean phase to delete this destination directory.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml ?

Comment: This is purely a maven question, maybe generalizing it to be maven only, or adding the Java tag, would help bring in an audience that can help.  Also, a simplified version of your pom.xml to give more kontext is useful.

Comment: Sadly I haven't worked in Kotlin for some time no so I no longer have the pom.xml.  :/